# How was a looping possible with an Alaska Airlines plane?

Tags: aircraft-systems, flight-instruments

Someone has stolen an empty airplane from Seattle Airport and crashed it down after performing some loopings. I am wondering how this was possible.

([Source](https://www.smh.com.au/world/north-america/unauthorised-take-off-of-plane-near-seattle-20180811-p4zwxl.html))

Comment: where does in that article say that the aircraft performed "loopings"?

Comment: Are you asking how the loops were done or the aircraft was stolen? The title suggests the former but I feel you actually want to know the latter.

Comment: Related: [Can large airliners do aerobatics such as loops?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/15311/14897)

Answer (score 4):

Most aircraft are capable of basic positve G aerobatics, provided you have a skilled pilot in the cockpit who knows what they’re doing.   Similar maneuvers have been performed by test pilots during demonstrations of large aircraft.  In all instances where it has been done, it has not been sanctioned by the company.  An unloaded commercial aircraft like that is going to have a pretty good thrust to weight ratio, which is going to help for doing vertical maneuvers like loops.

While precision aerobatics require a good deal of airmanship, the basics are pretty simple.  I’m not surprised that a mechanic, albeit a suicidal one, with no pilot experience was able to do a basic loop - and a terrible one at that.