# Barrel Roll Airliner Landing

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, landing

[image]

Can this barrel roll in an airliner be ferformed by a skilled pilot? Is this real?

Comment: The video probably isn't real, but look at https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12261/is-it-possible-to-do-a-barrel-roll-in-a-large-aircraft-like-a-b737

Comment: Is the video fake? What do you *think*? Or, if you need to ask the question, *do* you even think? No, it's utterly fake. VTD with extreme prejudice; please don't post that kind of nonsense.

Comment: Yep.  Seems legit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible to perform a 1g barrel roll in an airliner? Possibly. If the load on the airframe is kept to one positive g, it should be possible. Bob Hoover might have tried it if given the chance. Boeing lead test pilot [Tex Johnson](https://youtu.be/NcLQLcUYRSw) did try it at least once on a demonstration flight.

Is it likely to ever happen (again)? No. No owner/operator would allow it. Then, there is the requirement for an aircraft to be certified to perform aerobatics per 14 CFR Part 23.2005. Which no Virgin Atlantic airliner is. I don’t know of any modern type certificated airliner that is certified for aerobatics.

Is this meme a fake? Yes.

Comment: A barrel roll is normally under 2G peak on the initial pull and recovery and at the high speed of an airliner it could be kept under 1.5 with little effort.  In fact after the initial pull you can complete the middle third while ballistic, at 0G.  As well, although they are only stressed for 2.5G in transport category, that's fully loaded. An airliner with no passenger load, just fuel, is likely good for well over 3 Gs.  I know of a CRJ900 that experienced over 3 Gs NEGATIVE in an upset incident, and was undamaged, mainly because the cabin was empty.